# C# WPF Disable mouse events for navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, events, navigation

I had the same problem as [this person](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85f39010-a9ef-45fd-879f-0784ffee9aec/how-to-remove-historynavigation-from-a-wpf-frame?forum=wpf) and now it works great, but I have another issue.

The navigation toolbar is hidden but the navigation is still possible using the mouse buttons and the return key. How can I totally disable navigation?

Comment: How do you navigate with a mouse when the navigation is not visible?

Comment: With the mouse buttons, on some mouse you have buttons on the side that allow navigation.